# Add date into array as YYYY-M-DD in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Now I have a textarea which I enter the date in format 2019-09-15, But I want the date to be printed as 2019-9-15, here is my approach

```
  getDifferenceInDays(startDate, endDate) {
let dateArray = [];
let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
let day = currentDate.getDate() + 1;
let month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
let year = currentDate.getFullYear();

currentDate = [year, month, day].join("-");
let endOfDate = new Date(endDate);
let endDay = endOfDate.getDate() + 1;
let endMonth = endOfDate.getMonth() + 1;
let endYear = endOfDate.getFullYear();

endOfDate = [endYear, endMonth, endDay].join("-");
let todayDate = new Date(currentDate);
while (todayDate <= new Date(endOfDate)) {
  dateArray.push(currentDate);
  todayDate = todayDate.addDays(1);
  #   currentDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
return dateArray;
```

Now I am getting the currentDate as 2019-9-15, but if the startDate is 2019-09-15 and endDate is 2019-09-17 then the currentDate has to be updated like

2019-9-15
2019-9-16
2019-9-17

The line # when I debugged, it says currentDate.setDate as undefined, any solutions to this ? if it helps the entire line throws error

In short I want the date to be displayed as 2019-9-15 and it should increase as per the endate

Comment: What do u want actually ? Do u want to display date from startDate to endDate in Array ?

Comment: I want the date to be pushed into the array inthis format 2019-9-15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.Fyi, you can compare dates using `getTime()` method of Date object. Here is a full demo how you can generate date and show date from startDate to endDate in a format you mentioned (YYYY-M-DD).The input here is static, just for demo purpose. Obviously, you could make it dynamic on your own.

```js
function getDifferenceInDays(startDate, endDate) {
    let dateArray = [];

    let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
    let day = currentDate.getDate();
    let month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    currentDate = [year, month, day].join("-");

    let endOfDate = new Date(endDate);
    let endDay = endOfDate.getDate();
    let endMonth = endOfDate.getMonth()+1;
    let endYear = endOfDate.getFullYear();
    endOfDate = [endYear, endMonth, endDay].join("-");

    let todayDate = new Date(currentDate);
    while (new Date(todayDate).getTime() <= new Date(endOfDate).getTime()) {
        let formatTodayDate =  new Date(todayDate).getFullYear() +'-'+  (new Date(todayDate).getMonth() + 1) +'-'+ new Date(todayDate).getDate()
        dateArray.push(formatTodayDate);
        todayDate = new Date(todayDate).setDate(new Date(todayDate).getDate()+1);
    }
    
    let demo = document.getElementById("demo")
    demo.innerHTML = dateArray

    //return dateArray;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="getDifferenceInDays('2019-05-15', '2019-05-20')">Show Date</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
currentDate = [year, month, day].join("-");
```

Strings don't have a `setDate` method.

Logging the data you're operating on (or inspecting it at a breakpoint) would have shown you the problem *immediately*, and it would have been faster than asking on SO.

Comment: Hi, This I have already implemented, currentDate is not being incremented and thats what I want to achieve

Comment: @BharatRadhakrishnan I don't understand the issue then--that's how you add a day to a date. If you uncomment that line *now* then of course it fails, you need to make a date out of `currentDate` before you can call `setDate` on it.

Comment: I know the approach is wrong, I am asking if you have any idea

Comment: ... You can do it the way you are now if you create an actual `Date`.

Comment: @BharatRadhakrishnan No clue, but if I was to guess likely because it was never clear what actual problem you were having, and you didn't seem to understand that you already had the answer in your code, but didn't want to convert your string to a date.